# how to limit character length in essential addon for elementor form

Tags: php, character, maxlength

I tried to target in php the following form
[image]

I tried this code :

Username limit character length.
[image]

i also tried this one separatly :

```php
 if( strlen( $fields['form_field_password'] ) < 8 ) { return ['form_field_password', 'The password requires at least 8 characters' ]; }
```

nothing seems to work.
I checked with a friend developer, he told me that apparently the problem is the way I target the concerned field, not the code itself.

So please can someone help me to target the field ?

Comment: Post the code, not screenshots of the code.

Comment: here is the code : jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#eael-user-login").attr("maxlength","5");
});


the support of essential addon for elementor gave it to me, but it doesn't work, if anyone here have a solution, whether in php or Javascript, please tell me, i'm listening.

Answer (score 2):

edit :
I contacted the support of essential addons for elementor and learned few things !

First. You must use this code in JQuery :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#form-field-user_name").attr("maxlength","10");
 });
```

this work for the registration username

and this work for the password registration :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#form-field-password").attr("minlength","5");
 });
```

the principe is simple : The variable under the # depend on the input id. You just have to right click on the form you want to modify and see what is the input id and replace this value accordingly to your needs.

I don't want you to suffer like i suffered guys ! let's make the world better !

Enjoy it !